# How to quickly count number of 0(s) in a binary list?

Tags: python

With an array like `[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]`, is there a quick way to return the number of `0(s)`, which is `5` in the example? Thanks!

Comment: There are plenty of duplicates here and online...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `list.count`:

```
your_list.count(0)
```

And the help:

```
>>> help(list.count)
Help on method_descriptor:

count(...)
    L.count(value) -> integer -- return number of occurrences of value
```

Comment: I feel ashamed for asking this question.

Comment: @Rock well - on the plus side - you won't forget it any time soon ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
li = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
print len(li) - sum(li)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [16]: l = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]

In [17]: l.count(0)
Out[17]: 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Your choice, whatever lets you sleep at night:

```
l = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]

print l.count(0)
# or maybe:
print len(filter(lambda a: a == 0, l))
# or maybe:
print len([0 for x in l if x==0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can speed things up by a factor of 100 by using arrays (, which only becomes important for large lists)...

This should be 100 times faster than `my_list.count(0)`:

```
(my_array==0).sum()
```

However it only helps, if your data is already arranged as a numpy array (or you can manage to put it into a numpy array when it is created). Otherwise the conversion `my_array = np.array(my_list)` eats the time.